# pandas join two object columns in one dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join

I would like to join two columns to create a new column in a pandas dataframe :

df:

```
 id  v_1   v_2                         v_3
 35  'dfa' [u'cszc', u'bdv', u'yhs']   [u'cszc', u'bdv']  
 78  'dfa' [u'scaw', u'ygf', u'ompt']  [u'ompt', u'bdv']
 99  'dfa' [u'svca', u'yve', u'wwca']  [u'thbsd', u'tbs']
```

I need:

```
 id  v_1   v_2                         v_3                         new_v_4    new_v_5
 35  'dfa' [u'cszc', u'bdv', u'yhs']   [u'cszc', u'bdv', 'zv']     [u'bdv']  2/3
 78  'dfa' [u'scaw', u'ygf', u'ompt']  [u'ompt', u'bdv', 'tyn']    [u'ompt'] 1/3
 99  'dfa' [u'svca', u'yve', u'wwca']  [u'thbsd', u'tbs']               []     0
```

The "new_v_4" is to collect the intersections of column "v_2" and "v_3".
The "new_v_5" is the percentage of the size of intersection over the size of "v_2".
The "v_2" and "v_3" schema is object.
I prefer "new_v_4" is an array of string.
I tried to use "join" but do not know how to join the two object columns in one dataframe.

Raw input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[35, 'dfa', [u'cszc', u'bdv', u'yhs'],   [u'cszc', u'bdv']],
[78, 'dfa', [u'scaw', u'ygf', u'ompt'],  [u'ompt', u'bdv']],
[99, 'dfa', [u'svca', u'yve', u'wwca'],  [u'thbsd', u'tbs']]], columns=['id','v_1','v_2','v_3'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the intersection by `list(set & set)`

```
df['new_v_4'] = [list(set(a) & set(b)) for a, b in zip(df.v_2, df.v_3)]
```

Percentage can be calculated in a similar list comprehension.

```
df['new_v_5'] = [len(a)/len(b) for a, b in zip(df.new_v_4, df.v_2)]
```

Result

```
   id  v_1                v_2           v_3      new_v_4   new_v_5
0  35  dfa   [cszc, bdv, yhs]   [cszc, bdv]  [cszc, bdv]  0.666667
1  78  dfa  [scaw, ygf, ompt]   [ompt, bdv]       [ompt]  0.333333
2  99  dfa  [svca, yve, wwca]  [thbsd, tbs]           []  0.000000
```

Comment: thanks, I tried your query, it seems that the new column "new_v_4" just collect all intersected letters (including "u", which should not be there) not word level intersection.

Comment: Sounds like you have stringified list in `v_2` or `v_3`.  could you check the type of data in `v_2` and `v_3`?

Comment: Your solution works, at least for the given input. OP's data must not be like they say it is.